# How do you delete a file that does not have a file extension?

Tags: perl

How do you delete a file that does not have a file extension?

I'm using Strawberry Perl 5.32.1.1 64 bit version. Here is what I have:

```
unlink glob "$dir/*.*";
```

I've also tried the following:

```
my @file_list;
opendir(my $dh, $dir) || die "can't opendir $dir: $!";
while (readdir $dh){
    next unless -f;    
    push @file_list, $_;
}
closedir $dh;

unlink @file_list;
```

The result of this is that all files with an extension are deleted,
but those files without an extension remain undeleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really explain what the problem is, so this is just a guess.

You're using `readdir()` to get a list of files to delete and then passing that list to `unlink()`. The problem here is that the filenames that you get back from `readdir()` do not include the directory name that you originally passed to `readdir()`. So you need to populate your array like this:

```
push @file_list, "$dir/$_";
```

In a comment you say:

> I'm testing unlink glob "$dir/*.*"; but the files without file extensions are not deleted.

Well, if you think about it, you're only asking for files with an extension. If the pattern you pass to `glob()` contains `*.*`, then it will only return files that match that pattern (i.e. files with a dot and more text after the dot).

The solution would seem to be to simplify the pattern that you are passing to `glob()` so it's just `*`.

```
unlink glob "$dir/*";
```

That will, of course, try to delete directories as well, so you might want this instead:

```
unlink grep { -f } glob "$dir/*";
```

Answer (score 4):

You expect `glob` to perform DOS-like globbing, but the [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) function provides `csh`-like globbing.

- `glob("*.*")` matches all files that contains a `.`, ignoring files with a leading dot.
- `glob("*")` matches all files, ignoring files with a leading dot.
- `glob("* .*")` matches all files.

Note that every kind of file is matched. This includes directories. In particular, note that `.` and `..` are matched by `.*`.

If you want DOS-style globs, you can use [File::DosGlob](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::DosGlob).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `glob`, but you need to do a little more work than that.  [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) can help select the files you are looking for.

`*` grabs all entries (which do not begin with a dot), `-f` selects only files, `!/\./` removes files with a dot in the name:

```
unlink grep {!/\./} grep {-f} glob "$dir/*";
```